# Copy & Paste a file utility for terminal

Tags: command-line

I primarily use the terminal for file management and day-to-day tasks on my computer. There is one feature that I miss consistently and that is a copy/cut and paste for *files* (not clipboard text).

More specifically say I'm organizing files and I need to copy several files to different locations on the drive, I would do something like `cp /path/to/first/file /path/to/where/it/goes`, when dealing with lots of files with long file-names it is a little bulky. Its annoying especially if you aren't sure where the file is supposed to go (i.e. which specific subfolder)

I was wondering if there is a utility similar to the copy/paste paradigm in most graphic file managers. I.e. you do something like  `copy file`, navigate to the the directory you want and do `paste file`. Rather than explicitly writing out the copy-to path as with `cp` above.

I already have a rudimentary script that I wrote doing this, but I was wondering if there is an "official" or a fully-featured command line utility for this.

Comment: I guess a command line file manager like midnight commander (`mc`) is out of question?

Answer (score 2):

This [bash alias from WebUpD8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/copy-paste-files-from-command-line-bash.html) might be exactly what you are looking for?